# CSS - Positioning of element (Absolute header, body, fixed footer)

Tags: html, css

I'm rather new to html and css and I'm currently stuck with two annoying problems.

1. Unless my header's position is absolute it won't cover a small area above and beneath itself. But when the position is absolute the container beneath it partially goes behind the header.

**I want my header to cover the same area as it does when it's position is absolute, but I want the container's position to automatically be right beneath the header.**

2. When I divide the footer in half, for "Start" to be on the left side and "Contact" on the right side, and add the Copyright part as a float:right everything else on the line gets pushed to the side.

**I want "Start" and "Contact" to expand from the middle, out to the sides, while the Copyright part is to the far right. Everything on the same line.**

The header's opacity is only to show the problem.
The line in the middle is to make sure the footer's text is in the middle.
I want to avoid a scroll bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/swvyrLnf/

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the header: Set the header height to 100px. Then set the margin-top of your body to 100px.

For the scroll bar: This is partially determined by the height of the body. If you want to avoid the scroll bar then you will probably need to change the body height from 100%.

For the Contact/Share links: I'd add padding left/right so that they separate from one another. To make them stretch farther you could change the size of the text. Another option would be to put them in a container of say width 40% and make the whole container a link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though I would like to refrain from adding px to anything, is that possible? Since the scroll bar doesn't appear until I add a specific number of px to anything. Also I want to keep the 100% height for the page to adapt after the user's window size. And to the last answer - my main problem isn't to separate the links, but to make them centered in the middle of the page. The text to the right push them to the left.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `header` should have `overflow: hidden;` and then you are fine. It's because the items inside have `margin` that extends the container.

Comment: Nothing happened when I added "overflow: hidden;". Have I done something wrong?